# Tried plotting a heatmap but the plot is blackish and there are numbers at the side instead of column title

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

i wanted to find which columns are most related to each other for a linear regression project

dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/320/student+performance

here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import missingno
from matplotlib import pyplot
data = pd.read_csv('student-mat.csv',sep=";")

print(data.info())

print(data.columns)

data = data[['school', 'sex','reason','studytime','internet', 'romantic','famrel','health','absences','failures','paid','higher','G1','G2','G3']]
data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['school', 'sex','paid', 'higher', 'internet', 'romantic', 'reason'], drop_first=True, dtype=int)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.heatmap(data)
plt.show()
```

and i got this result
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yglsb.png)

Comment: if you don't calculate the cross correlation you don't get it plotted

Comment: What are you trying to do with `get_dummies`? pandas has a built-in function to compute correlation between columns: [corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

Comment: @Tranbi i was trying to change the categorical data to integers